# query guice dependency graph

Tags: java, guice

I'm trying to reuse a class written long ago by someone else. Guice is already used everywhere, so I just add the class to the constructor where I want it, provide its direct dependencies, and hope for the best. The result is a long list of missing dependencies at runtime. Going back to the original context in which my desired class was used, I find a module with many sub-modules, and I don't recognize anything. Basically what I'm looking at is a large graph, and I want to find the path that Guice followed to resolve each missing dependency. And I'll decide which point along the path to install in my target module.

Does Guice provide a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to inspect the way dependencies are injected, consider the [Grapher](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Grapher) extension. If you want to write your own inspector to visualize the module tree, Guice also provides an API to [inspect Modules at runtime](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/InspectingModules).